#  Is the program correct?

Tags: assembly, intel, 8085

The following is the program that i wrote for multiplying 2 ,8 bit numbers. One of my friends told that the program is incorrect. I couldn't verify it, so i wanted to verify it. I have just started to learn assembly programming. The following program uses lots of registers.

```
LDA C001H
MOV B,A
LDA C002H
MOV D,A
MOV C,0H
CMP C
JZ ZRESULT    // CHECKED FOR C002
MOV A,B
CMP C
JZ ZRESULT    // CHECKED FOR COO1

LOOP :  ADD A
        MOV E,A
        LDA 01H
        DEC D
        CMP D
        JZ ANSWER
        JNZ LOOP



 ZRESULT : LDA 0H
           STA 2500H
           OUT PORT1

 ANSWER :  MOV A,E
           STA 2500H
           OUT PORT1
```

Is this program correct ? If not please tell the corrections in it.

Comment: You could have more confidence in your program if you try multiplying a pile of numbers together and checking the results: check especially when one or more numbers are `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, powers of two, and numbers that are one greater than or less than powers of two, and inputs that will force overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that multiplying two 8-bit numbers could give you a 16-bit result.  You're only giving an 8-bit result, though.

You need to do something with the carry result of the `ADD A` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to detect overflow in the addition loop.  A naïve way would be to check if the result decreases after the addition.  Take as an example 20*13.  20*12 will give 240 in the register, but add 20 to that and you won't get 260, you'll get 4 (260%256).

A better way would be to check the carry flag in the condition register.